# Align vertically a div inside bootstrap row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I cannot figure out how to align the div containing the "Go" button vertically to bottom.

I tried several things but none worked.

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2fzq3xb3/2/

and here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>align div to bottom inside div</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="#">
     <div class="row" style="position: relative;">
      <div class="col-xs-10">
          <div class="row">
              <div class='col-xs-6'>
                  <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="start-date">Start date</label>
                      <div class='input-group date' id='start-date'>
                          <input type='text' class="form-control" id='start_date' name='start_date' />
                          <span class="input-group-addon">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                          </span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class='col-xs-6'>
                  <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="end-date">End date</label>
                      <div class='input-group date' id='end-date'>
                          <input type='text' class="form-control" id='end_date' name='end_date' />
                          <span class="input-group-addon">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                          </span>
                      </div>
                      <?php 
                      ?>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
         <div class="col-xs-2" style="position: relative; bottom: 50%;transform: translateY(-50%);">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Go</button>
         </div> 
     </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to the parent div.

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
```

Comment: make sure you set a height on the parent and child.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I found. Any suggestions for improvements are welcome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>align div to bottom inside div</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="#">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-10" style="max-width: 500px;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class='col-xs-6'>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="start-date">Start date</label>
                            <div class='input-group date' id='start-date' style="max-width: 230px;">
                                <input type='text' class="form-control" id='start_date' name='start_date' />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-xs-6'>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="end-date">End date</label>
                            <div class='input-group date' id='end-date' style="max-width: 230px;">
                                <input type='text' class="form-control" id='end_date' name='end_date' />
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <?php 
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2" style="height:74px;">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-ss" style="position:absolute; bottom: 15px;">Go</button>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just make sure `row` has its `position` property set to `static` (default value). I don't know why, but if you change it to `relative` or `absolute` it won't work.

```css
.col-xs-12 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    some text...
  </div>
</div>
```